# debounceTime of rxJS works when working in local, but after build it is not working as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using debounceTime & distinctUntilChanged for a form valueChanges.

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(100000), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => {
......
});
```

when i am working in local, works perfectly. Triggers after 10 seconds and i have no issues.

But, after i build --prod, it is not working as expected.

the subscribe is triggered for each change i typed,

Thanks in advance.

```
import {debounceTime,distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(100000), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => {
......
});
```

Comment: In [debouceTime()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime), time is in milliseconds. So `100000` would be equal to 100 seconds, not 10 seconds.

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz it will be great because the code has no issues at all!

Comment: ok it is a typo. it was 10000, for 10 seconds.

Comment: @Shorbagy.

It will work fine if i provide a stackblitz, the issue for me happneing only after prod build of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake.

I used a dynamic value for milliseconds, the value was 0. So it triggered oddly.

Thanks you everyone, and apologies for wasting your time. :)